# How to use passphrase for RSAPrivateKey in JAVA?

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, rsa

I encrypt and decrypt with RSA 2048 keys. But for additional security I need to use passphrase for RSAPrivateKey with a AES 128 method.

I can generate this keys, but I don't know how to use them in **JAVA**.

In my code I initialize private (witout passphrase) key (public is the same):

```
String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_RSA = "src/pri.der";
File privKeyFile = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_RSA);

// read private key DER file
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(privKeyFile));
byte[] privKeyBytes = new byte[(int) privKeyFile.length()];
dis.read(privKeyBytes);
dis.close();
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

// decode private key
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
RSAPrivateKey privKey =(RSAPrivatKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
```

And use:

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(pubKey, privKey);
...
```

I need for any information or examples how to enter there passphrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://www.juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/) solution is better for me.

I used not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar.
For example:

```
//path to private key file
String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_RSA = "C:\\Users\\Adey";
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_RSA);
// passphrase - the key to decode private key
String passphrase = "somepass";
PKCS8Key pkcs8 = new PKCS8Key(in, passphrase.toCharArray());
byte[] decrypted = pkcs8.getDecryptedBytes();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decrypted);
RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(spec);
```

Comment: the link is not working, please next time write the solution and pref the link.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use PBE (Password Based Encrytion) to protect private key with a password. After some research that I made for you the following code sample may help you:

```
//Generating keypairs
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

// extract the encoded private key, this is an unencrypted PKCS#8 private key
byte[] encodedprivkey = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

// We must use a PasswordBasedEncryption algorithm in order to encrypt the private key, you may use any common algorithm supported by openssl, you can check them in the openssl documentation http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html
String MYPBEALG = "PBEWithSHA1AndDESede";
String password = "pleaseChangeit!";

int count = 20;// hash iteration count
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
random.nextBytes(salt);

// Create PBE parameter set
PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(MYPBEALG);
SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(MYPBEALG);

// Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

// Encrypt the encoded Private Key with the PBE key
byte[] ciphertext = pbeCipher.doFinal(encodedprivkey);

// Now construct  PKCS #8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo object
AlgorithmParameters algparms = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(MYPBEALG);
algparms.init(pbeParamSpec);
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encinfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(algparms, ciphertext);

// and here we have it! a DER encoded PKCS#8 encrypted key!
byte[] encryptedPkcs8 = encinfo.getEncoded();
```

See also [Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html)

Comment: Security enhancements: 1024-bit RSA is a bit on the small size (i.e. the NSA can likely crack it), better use 2048-bit.  Better to use PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 than PBEWithSHA1AndDESede, and number of iterations should be at least 10,000.

Comment: Right! @TheGreatContini the above code is just a template and everyone have to make some changes to fit it with his needs. Your notes are very helpful because in case of cryptography it doesn't matter only what algorithm you use but which security parameters  you use with them.

Comment: @Dimitris Baltas, thank you for your answer! Maybe I didn't understand you but I need to generate the keys in openssl and load them like a files. Next I should encrypt and save them in RSAPrivateKey class and use in Algorithm class. Finally I make a token String token = JWT.create().sign(algorithm);